# How to map CTRL-V to SHIFT-INSERT using KiTTY shortcuts?

Tags: kitty

I would like to map the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to generate a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>, effectively being able to "paste" what's in my Windows clipboard to my KiTTY terminal.

KiTTY allows shortcuts like so:

```
[Shortcuts]
list={CONTROL}{LEFT} {CONTROL}{RIGHT} {CONTROL}V
{CONTROL}{LEFT}=\x1bb\
{CONTROL}{RIGHT}=\x1bf\
{CONTROL}V=echo you have pressed CTRL+V
```

In effect:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> skips forward a word (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> skips backward a word (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> I get the "*you have pressed CTRL+V*", but I don't know how to configure it to emulate <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>.

Anybody knows how?

Answer (score 1):

To just map <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste from clipboard you add this line your `kitty.conf` file:

```
map ctrl+v write_to_terminal paste_from_clipboard
```